# ASP.NET - Data source can be configured on IIS instead of residing in Web.Config?

Tags: asp.net, connection-string, datasource, jndi

Is it possible to have a Data Source configured on IIS and get access to it from an Asp.Net application (Entity Framework), instead of configuring the connection in "Web.config" file of the web application?

I mean, I don't want to make database connection dependent of the application, but leave its configuration to the server. So the application can access it.

I know this kind of architecture is wildly used on Java EE applications, where datasource configuration resides on server and is accessed by its JNDI name.

How can we do that in IIS and Asp.NET with Entity Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach to share connectionstrings among different websites is placing it on [`machine.config`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229697(v=vs.90).aspx).

All web configs inherits from this file so any setting there is available on your application (unless you explicitly say not to do it).